# Android Browser - h1 tags rendering in what looks like wingdings , p tags render just fine

Tags: android, twitter-bootstrap, fonts

I've got an bootstrap site working cleanly on all browsers.
However when browsing on my Android phone, the H1 and H3 tags are written in what looks like wingdings font.  i've tried backing off the custom font and using the same css as the paragraph style but to no avail.

```
h1, h2, h3, h4 {
    font-family: Raleway, Georgia, Times, serif;
    -webkit-text-stroke: 1px;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
}

p, blockquote, body {
    font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}
```

i don't see any posts on this issue anywhere.  i've seen it on a couple of my sites. quite puzzled.  thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is a bug in bootstrap 2.3.1 (https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/pull/7310)

is broken on my android phone (htc mytouch) but looks perfect on chrome on windows 7.  are there are @media query to exclude just the chrome phone browsers?

to fix add this to your.css

```
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
    text-rendering: auto;
}
```